# How to implement many to many relationship in android-sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am having a table called pdreview in sqlite which is having two columns called reviewId and prid.

i want to implement many to many relationship between these two columns.

[image: Pdreview]

I will get the reviewId from the user.First i have declared prid as zero.
Based on  the reviewId i will increment the prid .If the reviewId inputted by the user already exists in the table it will increment the prid or else it will reinitialize to zero and increment.My problem is if the user inputs reviewId as after insertion of reviewId=2 record and Prid=2.I want this insertion before reviewId=1 and Prid=1 record and not after reviewId =2 and Prid =2

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: Do you really need duplicate entries in Prid column? That makes it a many-to-many relation. Make Prid unique and autoincrement, problem solved.

Comment: Yes both columns need duplicate values.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about your problem, but actually it seems to be only a "sort" problem. You seems to store correct data and the problem is when you request your data back.

Actually, I think you just have to sort on your `reviewId` :

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable ORDER BY reviewId
```

Comment: No.It is  not a sorting problem.I want the insertion to be done in such a manner.I don't want to fetch and display to the user.

Comment: so, I don't understand your problem. The "position" of your insertion is not an issue because you don't need to manage it. Maybe can you explain us your problem with more details ?

Comment: I want to implement many to many relationship between two mentioned columns.

Comment: position of insertion is also needs to be maintained as per the requirement

Comment: Ok ! So we come back on the position of insertion. I don't understand why you need to maintain this correctly... This position is only used for displaying back to screen, so if you don't want to display your record, I don't understand why you want to have them sorted.

Comment: OK!let it be.I did that requirement through ordinary java codings. If this is done using annotations,is it possible to achieve the requirement?

Comment: I will not change my point of view : I still don't understand why you need this requirement if it's not for displaying (and if so, it's resolved by my answer). Annotations or not, Java will not help you here to do something that should not be managed by your code (i.e. the position of the records *inside* the database)